# Launch image displayed upside down on iPad.

Tags: iphone, ios

I wonder if you have any idea of why my Launch image get displayed upside down when using the iPhone application/storyboard on the iPad simulator. After the launch image the orientation is correct.

Running on iPad device also has the correct orientation. It is only the when running iPhone application on iPad it does not work. iPhone all works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same thing happen on a real device?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem today without having changed the `UISupportedOrientation`-key (my app supports all 4 orientations) while I was changing values in the summary view (Xcode 4.2). The app started to do strange behaviours while loading the launch image, it changed the orientation to `upsideDown`. I solved the problem by just by changing the sequence of the 4 different orientation levels. 1st element was somehow `PortraitUpsideDown` and the 4th element `Portrait`, I swapped these two values and then it was working smooth again.